# Compress sqlite data, NSString or NSData?

Tags: ios, core-data, compression

Im using sqlite files to store data and a lot of the data I store is NSString format, if i store this data as NSData will it make the size of my sqlite files smaller? Is there anything else i can do to decrease sqlite file size?

Thanks.

Comment: Raw SQLite has no idea about NSString or NSData, so what exactly do you mean by "NSString format"?

Comment: In in the xcode data model editor, the entity Im working on has an attribute that has its data type set to String.

Comment: That's Core Data, not SQLite. Although SQLite is supported as a back-end, the encoding is an implementation detail whose details can change without notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated SQLite / CoreData can't really help you in this endeavor. You've already pointed out the correct solution, which is to use NSData to store raw bytes in the SQLite store and do the in-memory conversion yourself.

This will be exceptionally slow as compression is inherently expensive.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Set your attribute type to NSData
2. Check out [libz](http://www.zlib.net) and add it to your project in Xcode
3. Choose a compression flavor from libz
4. Implement custom properties to do the translation

   ```
   - (NSString *)getAttrString {
        NSData *bytes = self.attr
        //decompress
   }

   - (void)setAttrString:(NSString *)s {
       NSData *d = //compress
       self.attr = d;
   }
   ```

As others have mentioned there isn't really any benefit to compressing small strings, so you'll probably want to add a boolean to your model that indicates whether or not the data was actually compressed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped a lot. I managed to get my sqlite file down from 11.4MB to 4.2MB using a combination of converting the NSStrings to NSData and then using gzip compression.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this :
**save image link** instead of image.
If there is a large description then you can fetch it through a server.
Remove multiple data. ie; **duplicate data**
Remove the data that can be generated during runtime using the data in the database.
**Perform normalization** to optimise the database which will avoid and clean up the mess if present.

Answer (score 2):

Prajwal provided some good general tips for optimizing Core Data storage. To answer your specific question though: No, converting from `NSString` to `NSData` will not save any space and may actually use more space. `NSData` does not do any compression. To convert to `NSData` you'd want something like

```
NSData *myData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But that won't help and might make things worse. For example, if your string includes an "é", `NSString` represents it on one byte. But UTF-8 requires two bytes, so the `NSData` uses more space.

If you really want to compress the strings, there are open source implementations that will give you compressed `NSData` objects. Don't do that unless you have a **lot** of string data which you know will compress. It might save space, but (a) it will do so at the expense of speed, and (b) you won't be able to use those strings to look up objects in your data store.

If you **still** need to reduce the size of your data store, ask another question where you describe your data model. Different techniques apply depending on what your data model looks like.